# How to remove the filename from wc -l output?

Tags: bash, scripts, wc

I want to count the number of lines in a file using `wc -l` but only output the number, without the following space and filename. 
Edit from comments: The filename may have numbers in it.

Currently if I do:

```
wc -l /path/to/file
```

On a file with 176 lines, the output is:

```
176 /path/to/file
```

This is within a bash script, and the resulting number will be assigned as the value of a variable.

Comment: `wc -l < /path/to/file`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd use:

```
<file wc -l
```

Which contarily to `cat file | wc -l` doesn't need to fork a shell and to run another process (and runs faster):

```
% time </tmp/ramdisk/file wc -l     
8000000
wc -l < /tmp/ramdisk/file  0,07s user 0,06s system 97% cpu 0,132 total
% time cat /tmp/ramdisk/file | wc -l
8000000
cat /tmp/ramdisk/file  0,01s user 0,16s system 80% cpu 0,204 total
wc -l  0,09s user 0,10s system 94% cpu 0,203 total
```

(`/tmp/ramdisk/file` was stored in a ramdisk to take I/O and caching out of the equation.)

However for small files indeed the difference is neglectable.

---

Yet another way would be:

```
wc -l file | cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

Which in my tests performs approximately the same as `<file wc -l`.

Comment: or you could use `wc -l < /etc/passwd` . Same thing, just different syntax :)

Comment: Cheers, I'd tried using `cut` previously, but got hung up on using `-c` which wasn't useful as the line count could be of variable length.

Comment: Nice. I tried using cut as well, but clearly couldn't get the syntax right.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with a simple one liner using cat.
`cat deluge1.log | wc -l`

Answer too simple to require a long drawn out answer.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention that the filenames may have numbers in them!

Comment: I've ended up using an intermediate variable, with bash expansion, so `line_count=$(wc -l ${file})` then `no_of_lines="${line_count/ */}`

Comment: Proving once again there are many ways to accomplish the same result. ;-)

Comment: I definitely prefer the simple `cat` usage, to save on assigning more variables. Cheers for editing the question too, was just about to get round to that.

Comment: This is a [useless use of cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html) , but it sure works :)

Answer (score 0):

another cleaner option  wc -l filename | awk '{print $1}

example list of entries in a file

```
bash-4.1$ wc -l ../CBB_Nodes.txt | awk '{print $1}' 
398
bash-4.1$ 
without awk it would have been as usual with the file name. 

bash-4.1$ wc -l ../CBB_Nodes.txt
398 ../CBB_Nodes.txt
bash-4.1$
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple alternative that did the trick for me.

```
cat /c/dev/P2Working/.gitignore | wc -l
```

[image]